# linkElement.dispatchevent object doesn't support this action IE

Tags: internet-explorer, dispatchevent

My Code is like bellow:

```
         var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

            if (file.size != 0) {

                var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                var linkElement = document.createElement('a');

                linkElement.setAttribute('href', objectUrl);

                linkElement.setAttribute("download", fileName);

                var clickEvent;
                //This is true only for IE,firefox
                if (document.createEvent) {
                    // To create a mouse event , first we need to create an event and then initialize it.
                    clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
                    clickEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                }
                else {
                    clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
                        'view': window,
                        'bubbles': true,
                        'cancelable': true
                    });
                }                   
                linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

This code Works fine in chrome & mozila, only issue with IE 10 or above.

Can anyone please help me to get it working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This method is not suitable for for all the browsers.
So you can just simply go for using Filesaver.js https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Include Filesaver.js in your page and use saveAs method from this file as bellow.

```
var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
if (file.size != 0) 
{
  $window.saveAs(file, fileName);                   
}
```